# Vertx Timeout Exception occurred in Junits, despite it hitting VertexTestContext.completeNow() and message.reply

Tags: junit, vert.x, junit5

I am seeing these errors occur when ever I run my junit code. (using junit 5)

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while closing extension context: org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodExtensionContext@1e66f1f5
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Closing the Vertx context timed out
...

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The test execution timed out. Make sure your asynchronous code includes calls to either VertxTestContext#completeNow(), VertxTestContext#failNow() or Checkpoint#flag()

    at io.vertx.junit5.VertxExtension.joinActiveTestContexts(VertxExtension.java:239)
    ...
```

I have stepped through my code, and all futures were completed and the vertx's message object had reached the Message.reply statement., and according to the debugger the VertexTestContext.completeNow() had been reached. Yet still the error persists.

The code in each test method is as such.

```
vertx.eventBus().send(createPaymentScheduleVerticleAddress, jsonObject, deliveryOptions,
      vertxTestContext.succeeding(response -> vertxTestContext.verify(() -> {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(response.body());
        vertxTestContext.completeNow(); <-- it has reached here, and countdown became 0 after this. Able to see the expected relay in response.
      })));
```

The implementation code for my handle method that is as such inside the vertx.eventBus().consumer(address, this::handle)

```
  future.setHandler(stageResp -> {
    if (stageResp.succeeded()) {
      log.info(CLASS_MARKER, "insertion successful: ");
      message.reply(message.body(), replyOptions); <-- has reached here.
```

Comment: Could you please provide executable snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the answer was.

What happened is that in the tearDown function, the future was mocked and was not done in way that it would continue calling its lamda expression.
The completeNow function was in the lamda expression.

Using doAnswer to handle that lamda expression resolved it.